# updating iPhone apps via the web

Tags: iphone, updates

I'm working on an eBook app for the iPhone.  Given the time it takes for Apple to review and publish updates, I'm considering adding a feature to update the content via my own (Google App Engine-powered) web site.

This would allow me to update the content at will, rather than being at the mercy of the App Store review team.  Is Apple likely to reject this kind of behavior in an app?  I've asked in the Apple Developer forums, but received no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have developed an application on the App Store that will go our web server and get new content when new content is available and store it on the iPhone.  You should not have any problem as long as the content is not offensive.  This could lead to your application being removed from the app Store.  I've also heard that they may make your app 17+ because of getting content from the web.

Answer (score 1):

You probably received no response because no one knows for sure.  Apple has allowed apps that embed webkit before, but it has also rejected them as well.

Answer (score 0):

iphone + web hybrid apps perfectly ok i think, not sure why apple would be concerned.